# Patron de diseño para tareas a tiempos regulares

Tags: java, revisión-de-código

Tengo un caso, que no es la primera vez que enfrento, y quisiera una revision de código.

El asunto es que tengo una tarea, que se debe correr cada cierto tiempo X (no exactamente X, la precisión es deseable pero no mandataria, una aproximación esta bien).

Lo que usualmente hago es lo siguiente:

```
class Servicio implements Runnable {

    private volatile boolean running = true;

    @Override
    void run() {
        while(this.isRunning()) {
            try { 
                // operaciones I/O y procesamiento

                // Espero el tiempo X
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
               // no hago nada, que de vez en cuando el ciclo se ejecute
               // de forma no muy precisa no es un problema. 
            } catch (otras excepciones que me interesa atrapar) {
               // quizá stopRunning(), quizá no
               // ya que las partes de I/O tienen retry polices,
               // pero si por ejemplo recibo File Not Found o 404, no quiero seguir.
            } 
        }
    }

    public synchronized void stopRunning() {
       this.running = false;
    }

    public synchronized boolean isRunning() {
       return this.running;
    }
}
```

Adicionalmente, `stopRunning()` puede ser invocado desde otro thread.

Pregunta:

¿Que diseño alternativo puedo utilizar?
¿Cuales son las ventajas / desventajas de este método frente al método propuesto?

Comment: Para los lectores, esta pregunta no debería ser cerrada. Leer [este enlace](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/164/227) para más información.

Comment: No entiendo por qué no puedes utilizar Timers. Más bien, bajo esa limitante, ¿significa que tampoco puedes usar schedulers?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza de acuerdo, aceptare otras alternativas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si piensas utilizar Java puro, te recomendaría utilizar el framework `ExecutorService` vía la interfaz `ScheduledExecutorService` para manejar tus tareas que se ejecuten cada cierto tiempo.

Si puedes utilizar un framework, te recomiendo Quartz puesto que permite crear crons y ejecutar una tarea por cada cron. Asimismo, te permite ejecutarlos de manera sincronizada. Esto significa que, para un cron, si una tarea demora más del tiempo estimado, las otras tareas en lugar de ejecutarse y posiblemente corromper datos, se quedarán encoladas y esperarán a que se libere (o se corte por alguna otra razón) las tareas pendientes.